# How can I repair a leak in a sink drain pipe cleanout?

Tags: plumbing

I have a leak coming from the connection point (sorry, don’t know what the name of this part is) in the pipe.  Can I just tighten this or should I be replacing the whole pipe?
[image]

Comment: That is a clean out cap/cover for the drain line.  Would remove and clean the threads and put back on.  It is possible you might need to clean that line out if water is near the cap.  Is that on the floor or on a wall?

Comment: I would also add a few wraps of teflon tape dope.

Comment: open it an figure out how its supposed to seal then fix it so that it does, (maybe it has an o ring that needs to be replaced? maybe it is just loose.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input, the job was very easy

Answer (score 1):

Clean the pipe threads thoroughly with a soft brush, since they'll have some debris buildup by now.  Then, apply **pipe joint compound**, commonly called **pipe dope** by plumbers, to the threads of the clean-out cover.  That will solve the leak.

You can purchase pipe joint compound at any plumbing supply shop or the plumbing aisle of a home improvement store.  Oatey Great White is common in my area.

Pipe joint compound is not a glue or welding substance.  It's more like a liquid gasket.  It won't cause the threads to get stuck.  This allows normal use of the clean-out cover in the future.  It's a good idea to clean & replace pipe joint compound whenever you need to remove & re-install a clean-out cover.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this was easy to fix